# suggesting friends that are not already a friend with the user

Tags: php, mysql

I want to suggest a friends for user. I need to validate if the friend am suggesting  are not a friend already  with the user
I have 2 tables called User, friendship

I try this code but I can't proceed coz I have no more idea

```
$sql=“SELECT user.fullname,user.userID FROM users WHERE user. userID NOT 
     IN( SELECT * FROM friendship WHERE userID = '$userID') “;
```

I'm using php and mysql

Comment: Would be helpful to provide your table schema(s)

Comment: Show your table schema(s)...

Answer (score 1):

Try with `friendship.userID`

```
$sql = "SELECT user.fullname,user.userID FROM users WHERE user. userID NOT 
 IN( SELECT friendship.userID FROM friendship WHERE userID = '$userID')";
```

You need to check with the UserIds that are already friends of the user

Answer (score 0):

This May Help You..

```
function addFriend() {

global $userid, $friendid;

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE userid = $userid AND friendid =     $friendid");

if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 1) {
   exit("Youre already friend with this user");
} else {

$sql = "INSERT INTO friends (userid, friendid) VALUES ($userid, $friendid)";
mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_affected_rows()) {
  echo "Success";
else 
  echo "Failure";
}
}
```